# ISNULL on NTEXT causes fatal exception on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a weird error that occurs on a client's SQL Server 2005 box.  We have provided them with a dataview that is populated with a query with a CTE with several joins / subqueries that does some text value interpretation on an NTEXT field that contains an XML blurb

*I know that we could have used used other field types and / or methods, but it is what it is for good reason that I hope I would not have to explain here.*

The problem is that for some reason, this query creates a fatal exception on the SQL Server.

Herewith a condensed version of the business end of the actual T-SQL that causes the error

```
declare @@dtDateStart datetime, @@dtDateEnd datetime
set @@dtDateStart = getdate()
Set @@dtDateEnd = dateadd(year, 1, @@dtDateStart)
;with  qItems
    (date_created, SYSTEM_ID, LegalEntity) as
(   select i.date_created,
        i.externalKey as SYSTEM_ID,
        case when i.HasLegalEntity > 0 then
            substring(i.message, charindex('<LegalEntity>',i.message)+13, charindex('</LegalEntity>',i.message)-charindex('<LegalEntity>',i.message)-13)
         else '' end as LegalEntity
    from (select *, charindex('<LegalEntity>', message) as HasLegalEntity from dbo.INT_Error_Queue) as i
    where i.date_created between @@dtDateStart and @@dtDateEnd)
select 
    QItems.date_created, 
    QItems.SYSTEM_ID, 
    Qitems.LegalEntity
from QItems
WHERE
(isnull(Qitems.LegalEntity, '') not in (select key_value from Special_app_Settings where key_name = 'EntityName'))
```

At first I suspected that it has something to do with the where clause, because the `[key_value]` on `[Special_app_Settings]` is of type `nvarchar(4000)`, and `[i].[message]` on `[INT_Error_Queue]` is of type `[ntext]`, but I am not sure whether that would cause the error I have.  If I remove the where clause, the error does not occur.

Herewith the dump from the SQL Server Log:

```
03/13/2013 10:30:24,Server,Unknown,A user request from the session with SPID 101 generated a fatal exception. SQL Server is terminating this session. Contact Product Support Services with the dump produced in the log directory.
03/13/2013 10:30:24,Server,Unknown,Error: 17310<c/> Severity: 20<c/> State: 1.
03/13/2013 10:30:24,spid101,Unknown,External dump process return code 0x20000001.<nl/>External dump process returned no errors.
...
03/13/2013 10:30:20,spid101,Unknown,* BEGIN STACK DUMP:
03/13/2013 10:30:20,spid101,Unknown,*
03/13/2013 10:30:20,spid101,Unknown,* *******************************************************************************
03/13/2013 10:30:20,spid101,Unknown,SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 101 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.
03/13/2013 10:30:20,spid101,Unknown,***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0039.txt
03/13/2013 10:30:20,spid101,Unknown,Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
```

Does anyone have any idea as to WHY this occurs?

Comment: For starters, have you considered using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` since `NTEXT` has been deprecated? Or maybe even using `XML` if you're storing XML?

Comment: Thanks, I knew someone would say that.  Problem is that this specific release uses these field types, and it won't change until the next major release of our software.  We have various other custom in-house developed replication (and other) procedures that are incompatible with NVARCHAR(MAX) and XML, so it will def not change in this version.  I cannot make any database schema changes at this point.

Comment: Have you tried just removing the isnull from the where clause?  Not that I see any reason why that would cause a problem.  Or re-writing it as a NOT EXISTS statement rather than a NOT IN?  Also is there anything useful in the stack dump that the error references?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return on your system?

Comment: @KennethFisher - I have tried it without the `isnull` and there was no change.  I will try the `NOT EXISTS` though.  Note that the sub-query to `Special_app_Settings` will only ever return up to 3 records. I have sifted through the stack dump, and apart from what I have posted, there is only dll version info, a portion of my original query, and loads of hex.

Comment: @SebastianMeine - I'll get back to you soonest with that information

Comment: @SebastianMeine: The correct version information is this: `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (X64) 
       Feb 10 2007 00:59:02 
       Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
       Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be a victim to problem I have seen before, introduced with Cumulative update for Service Pack 2. Is the compatibility level of your database 80 (SQL 2000)?

See [Microsoft KB 938102](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938102) for Hotfix details, but I suggest you upgrade to the latest service pack (or definitely a later cumulative service pack).

Essentially the Query Engine is evaluating your where clause and creating joins using non-ANSI operators such as *=, you then fall foul of this Sql bug. The problem occurs if the following conditions are true:

- The query references a view that uses non-ANSI outer join operators,
  For example, the view uses the *= operator or the =* operator.
- The column list of the SELECT statement in the view contains a
  subquery.
- The version of SQL Server 2005 is SQL Server 2005 SP2 or a later
  version.
- You set the database of SQL Server 2005 to use compatibility level
  80.

Comment: This definitely looks like it could be related.  I'll check the suggested workaround / solution and report back. Can you update the answer with detail from the link, in case the link dies?

Comment: Turns out they did in fact have SQL2005SP2 without the cumulative update as in the KB... The Query engine must have treated the where clause in my statement as an outer join, because in my code I did not use the old operators. I have found more supporting articles of this solution by googling Error 17310 as from the dump-log provided.  I have recommended applying newer SP's, also provided a workaround SQL statement with explicit ansi join operators. Good catch!